# count number of a char array appeared in another char array

Tags: java, arrays

the code should count number of a char array #1 appeared in another char array #2

but it keep adding one more count !!

```
public static int countSTR(char c1[], int c1Length, char c2[], int c2Length){
  int count=0;
  char last=c2[c2Length-1];
  for (int i=0;i<c1Length;i++)
     for (int j=0; j<c2Length;j++)

        if (c1[i]==c2[j])
              if(j+1==c2Length)
                 count++;

              else
                 continue; 
  return count;
 }
```

arrays I tested :

char [] str = {'C','A','B','L','B','Y' ,'A','M','C','S','C'};

char []m={'M','C'};

the output : 3

it should be 1

Comment: What is the simplest example which shows this problem? Why are you checking for `if(j!=0)
              if(j+1==c2Length)` ?  What is `last` used for?

Comment: You want to count how many times the char array c2 occurs in the char array c1, right?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try my suggestion?

Comment: @StefanDollase yes how many times it occurs

Comment: Good, if the claimed results in my answer match your expectation, then you should probably have a look at it. I provided two example pairs of input and output.

Comment: @j.doe do you want to count overlapping occurrences or not ?

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/i-think-my-post-wasnt-received-well-because-i-made-grammatical-mistakes-what-c/291370#291370) little guide could serve maybe as a little step  to formulate your questions more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
public static int countSTR(char c1[], int c1Length, char c2[], int c2Length) {
    if (c1 == null || c2 == null || c1Length < 1 || c2Length < 1 || c1Length > c1.length || c2Length > c2.length)
        return 0;

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= c1Length - c2Length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < c2Length; j++)
            if (c1[i + j] == c2[j]) {
                if (j == c2Length - 1)
                    count++;
            } else
                break;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I tried it in another arrays it gave me an exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @j.doe, Yes! I've updated the code, please try again!

Comment: can I ask why i <= c1Length - c2Length and c1[i + j] , thanks it works but I want to understand it well

Comment: For c1[i + j]: when the first character in c2 matches and you continue to compare the second character in c2, you want to compare it to c1[i + 1], not c1[i]. Comparing to c1[i] means you always compare the character in c2 with current first character in c1. For i <= c1Length - c2Length, it's because of when you come to a position c1, the remaining characters in c1 is less than the length of c2, you know it's not going to match. And if continue into the comparison loop, c1[i + j] may case the exception you mentioned.

Comment: @JMYang in Java you don't need to pass the size of the array because arrays are objects, you can access their length as an attribute

Comment: @Dici I thought j.doe might want to compare part of the characters in the array, not all. In that case the length parameter is required.

Comment: @JMYang oh ok, makes sense. Thought you were a C programmer lost on a Java question :D

Comment: @Dici actually I didn't write any C/C++ program for almost 17 years. I have been using Java everyday since 2000. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have overcomplicated the process. Just increment the count when they are equal. The for loops will continue, without using continue.

```
for (int i=0;i<c1Length;i++){
    for (int j=0; j<c2Length;j++){

        if (c1[i]==c2[j]){
            count++;
         }

    }     
}
return count;
```

Comment: I should check that the whole charArray#2 is in charArray#1

Comment: @Heyyou to my understanding, he wants the compute the size of the intersection of the arrays

Comment: @Heyyou what I understood is that we need to count the number of elements in common

Comment: @Heyyou haha me too. Actually I had not read the question entirely. I'm not sure what to understand anymore

Answer (score 0):

You need to only increase the counter if you have a complete match. This should do the job:

```
private void run() {
    char[] text = "foo bar foobar".toCharArray();
    char[] searchWord = "foo".toCharArray();
    System.out.println(countOccurrences(text, searchWord)); // prints 2
    text = new char[] { 'C', 'A', 'B', 'L', 'B', 'Y', 'A', 'M', 'C', 'S', 'C' };
    searchWord = new char[] { 'M', 'C' };
    System.out.println(countOccurrences(text, searchWord)); // prints 1
}

private int countOccurrences(char text[], char searchWord[]) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int offset = 0; offset <= text.length - searchWord.length; offset++) {
        if (matchesAt(text, searchWord, offset)) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

private boolean matchesAt(char[] text, char[] searchWord, int offset) {
    for (int i = 0; i < searchWord.length; i++) {
        if (text[offset + i] != searchWord[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using Java 8's stream API:

```
public static int countSTR(char[] c1, char[] c2)
{
    if(c1 == null || c2 == null || c1.length == 0 || c1.length > c2.length)
        return 0;

    long result = IntStream.range(0, c2.length - c1.length+1)
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, c1.length)
                    .mapToObj(j -> c2[i+j]).toArray())
            .filter(array -> IntStream.range(0, c1.length)
                    .mapToObj(i -> c1[i] == (char)array[i])
                    .allMatch(bool -> bool == true))
            .count();

    if (result < Integer.MIN_VALUE || result > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
            (result + " cannot be cast to int without changing its value.");
    }

    return (int)result;
}
```

Also, there's no need to pass an int with the length of the arrays as you would in C since you can get an array's length by accessing `array.length`.